# SQL query for finding records

Tags: sql

I have a table named PAYMENT. Within this table I have a user ID, an account number, a ZIP code and a date. I would like to find all records for all users who have active and deactive then active again as Count.

This is how the table looks like:

```
| user_id | account_no | zip   |      date | register  |
|       1 |        123 | 55555 | 12-DEC-09 | active    |
|       1 |        123 | 55555 | 13-DEC-09 | disactive |
|       1 |        123 | 55555 | 14-DEC-09 | active    |
|       2 |        456 | 55555 | 14-DEC-09 | disactive |
|       3 |        789 | 55555 | 14-DEC-09 | disactive |
|       4 |        999 | 55555 | 14-DEC-09 | active    |
```

The result should look similar to this:

I use COUNT(user_id) so the result will only come our as

= 1

i dont know is this possible?

Comment: where is the your query

Comment: You don't seem to know what database engine you are using. That's not a good signal...

Comment: You explanation is not precise. You are looking for the number of users who were both active and inactive already and whose latest state is 'active'?

Comment: what is your expected result ?

Comment: i try to select COUNT(user_id) where register = 'active' and register = 'disactive'?

Comment: the result should come out only "1" because only 1 id result active and deactive and active>?

Comment: Please correct your tags. What DBMS are you using? If you want an answer in standard SQL, then say so in your request and remove all tags except 'sql'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to find users who were both active and inactive, you would group by user ID. (Your own approach `where register = 'active' and register = 'disactive'`cannot work, because register in a single record can only be either 'active' or 'disactive'. You must look at a group of records instead.)

```
select user_id
from mytable
group by user_id
having count(case when register = 'active' then 1 end) > 0
and count(case when register = 'disactive' then 1 end) > 0;
```

Then count:

```
select count(*)
from
(
  select user_id
  from mytable
  group by user_id
  having count(case when register = 'active' then 1 end) > 0
  and count(case when register = 'disactive' then 1 end) > 0
) users;
```

Comment: Thanks! now i get the logic here.